# Reading static files from public folder in play framework in production

Tags: docker, scala, playframework, static-files

I'm trying to make a route to a specific static file.
It is working when running in local but when I run it using docker I'm getting an error.

The file is present at:

```
public/robots.txt
```

I am accessing it using:

```
http://localhost:9000/robots.txt
```

Expectation - It should have no error and load properly.

The error I get:

```
[error] a.a.OneForOneStrategy - null
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at kamon.instrumentation.akka.instrumentations.akka_26.InstrumentNewExecutorServiceOnAkka26$.around(DispatcherInstrumentation.scala:109)
    at akka.dispatch.ThreadPoolConfig$ThreadPoolExecutorServiceFactory.createExecutorService(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala)
    at akka.dispatch.Dispatcher$LazyExecutorServiceDelegate.executor$lzycompute(Dispatcher.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.Dispatcher$LazyExecutorServiceDelegate.executor(Dispatcher.scala:44)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutorServiceDelegate.execute(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.ExecutorServiceDelegate.execute$(ThreadPoolBuilder.scala:219)
    at akka.dispatch.Dispatcher$LazyExecutorServiceDelegate.execute(Dispatcher.scala:43)
    at akka.dispatch.Dispatcher.registerForExecution(Dispatcher.scala:127)
    at akka.dispatch.MessageDispatcher.attach(AbstractDispatcher.scala:152)
    at akka.actor.dungeon.Dispatch.start(Dispatch.scala:121)
[error] p.c.s.n.PlayRequestHandler - Cannot invoke the action
akka.stream.AbruptTerminationException: Processor actor [Actor[akka://application/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-0/flow-1-0-headSink#-440110538]] terminated abruptly
```

In conf/routes

```
GET     /robots.txt        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="robots.txt")
```

Comment: Can you share the whole error you get? Can you also explain how you run it both locally and "in docker"?

Comment: @GaëlJ , Thank you for your response!!

In local I am running using -> `sbt -Dconfig.file=conf/local.conf run`   </br>

In docker I am running using -> `docker run -p 9000:9000 -e JAVA_OPTS="-Dconfig.file=/opt/app/conf/local.conf" application`    </br>

Whatever I mentioned above is the whole error I am getting.

Comment: How's the image/Dockerfile generated? What does it contain? What's the HTTP code you get when calling the URL?

Comment: I get 500 Internal server error.

For the docker image creation I am copying all the files, exposing few ports and starting the container.

Comment: @GaëlJ I have updated the complete error.Please take a look.